# Find PDF page count with Node (on Windows)

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, phantomjs, pdf.js

I did a lot of research (I guess not enough?) and am trying to find an easy to use library to find the page count of a PDF using Node.js. The library would need to be usable on a Windows OS.

Anyone know how best to approach this? Worst case situation, I was thinking about doing something with PhantomJS and the PDF.js library.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/node/getinfo.js ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it's built on pdf.js, [pdf2json](https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json) it should work in windows.

I managed to find the page count of a test document like so:

```
var PDFParser = require('pdf2json');
var pdfParser = new PDFParser();

pdfParser.on('pdfParser_dataReady', function(data) {
    var doc = data.PDFJS && data.PDFJS.pdfDocument && data.PDFJS.pdfDocument.numPages;
    console.log('Number of pages:', doc);
});
// pdfParser.on('pdfParser_dataError', _.bind(_onPFBinDataError, self));

pdfParser.loadPDF('test.pdf');
```

Comment: Out of the few solutions I've looked at, this one was the first solution that worked for me (using Node on Mac). I did have to access the page count using: `data.formImage.Pages.length`. Not sure if there's a better way, but the given solution (`data.PDFJS && …`) didn't work out of the box for me. Either way, +1! :)

Comment: Ah, this also worked: `console.log(parser.PDFJS && parser.PDFJS.pdfDocument && parser.PDFJS.pdfDocument.numPages);`. So, the `parser` object contains the `numPages`. Interesting!

Answer (score 1):

In its current version you get the total pages via pdf2json's `Pages` array:

```js
stream.pipe(new PDFParser())
  .on('pdfParser_dataReady', (data) => {
    const pageCount = data && data.formImage && data.formImage.Pages && data.formImage.Pages.length ? data.formImage.Pages.length : 0;
    console.log(pageCount);
  })
```