# Webpack load pdf and csv within react component

Tags: reactjs, pdf, webpack

Hi I've created a project based on the [React Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) I'm trying to resolve a pdf that's saved to my local file system within my react component

```
return(
  <div className={s.root}>
      <div className={s.container}>
        <h1>Results: {this.props.caseId}</h1>
        <h2>Data</h2>
        </div>
        <h2>Graph</h2>
        <div>
          <a href={require(this.state.graphPdf)} download={this.state.graph}>{this.state.graph}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
)
```

where `this.state.graphPdf` = /Users/[username]/Desktop/outputs/graphs/graph.pdf

but I receive the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module "."

  - Results.js:67 webpackMissingModule
    /Users/radhika/oncostem-digital-
project/src/routes/results/Results.js:67:1

  - Results.js:67 Results.render
    /Users/radhika/oncostem-digital-
project/src/routes/results/Results.js:67:1
```

I think the issue is that I'm missing a loader in the webpack.config file (I'm using the same one that's in the starter project). But I'm not too familiar with webpack loaders or webpack in general, so I'm not sure what the configuration should be.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643649/serving-static-pdf-with-react-webpack-file-loader

Comment: An appropriate loader has to be included for loading files in webpack, by default it understands only javascript. Loader is a utility which tells webpack how to handle certain type of files.