# Server a static pdf - Vue CLI - Webpack - issue

Tags: pdf, webpack, vue.js

I build a little front thanks to VueCLI (+ Vuetify).

I wanted to render a button where `onClick` open a new tab with a pdf located in the folder's tree of the project.

I have an error and after hours looking why, it's seems to be a webpack conf to modify.

I finally read this answer on S/O ; [Serving static pdf with react webpack file loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643649/serving-static-pdf-with-react-webpack-file-loader)

But I got an error saying `include: paths -> paths is not defined`

I have to admit that I have no clue how webpack works behind the scene so any help would be find.

Answer (score 12):

You probably don't need Webpack for this: you can just put it in your static folder and link to it `<a href="/static/mypdf.pdf">pdf</a>`. If you want to go the Webpack route, put it in your src/assets directory and import it and add it to data object:

```
import pdf from '../assets/mypdf.pdf'

//...
data: () => ({ pdf })
//...
```

Then use the link in your component:

```
<a :href="pdf">pdf</a>
```

You probably added `include: paths` to the loader config but you didn't define it, instead of modifying your image loader, add a new one for PDFs:

```
  {
    test: /\.(pdf)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      name: utils.assetsPath('[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  }
```

You can change `[name].[hash:7].[ext]` if you want, say you want to add a `pdfs` directory in assets instead of using the base assets directory you would use: `pdfs/[name].[hash:7].[ext]`

Comment: thanks @Ian Walter. Its work for me to view/download exising pdf file in assets folder. I did not needed to include path.

import pdf from '../assets/mypdf.pdf'
data: () => ({ pdf })
<a :href="pdf">pdf</a>