# REACT PDF: Cannot use the packages to show static PDF file

Tags: reactjs, pdf, relative-path, importerror, webpack-file-loader

I am trying to show a static pdf in React app. I have tried a lot of packages:

react-pdf

react-pdf-js

react-pdf-js-infinite

simple-react-pdf

pdfjs-dist

react-pdf-pages

They often say that we can use the URL, or pdf file for the props for the PDF component easily, but I cannot use either.

I had two main errors.

1. As I want to use myPDF for the props for the component, I write this:

   import myPDF from 'path/to/pdf_file';

then, render_some_component pdf:{myPDF}

Here is the error:

ModuleParseError in 
            Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

(When I comment that line, this kind of error disappears)

I used the file-loader in webpack config, I have tried many different ways but failed.

2. I use the pdf file directly for the props like this:

   render_some_component pdf:{'path/to/pdf_file'}

   - In the Console:

Warning: Setting up fake worker.

11:23:55.962 pdf.worker.js:349 Warning: Ignoring invalid character "33" in hex string

11:23:55.963 pdf.worker.js:349 Warning: Ignoring invalid character "79" in hex string

...
There are a lot of 'Ignoring invalid character' like that and it always ends with:

localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) InvalidPDFException {name: "InvalidPDFException", message: "Invalid PDF structure"}

- In the Network, Headers, I see:

Request URL:http://localhost:3000/myPdfFile.pdf

Request Method:GET

Status Code:200 OK

Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000

- but In the Network, Response, I see just the HTML layout.

I think the pdf file is loaded correctly but the package cannot recognize its PDF structure.

Except that two main errors, I had another error related to the Worker used in the packages but I don't know how to fix it:

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker'

(This is something relates to Chrome as people say Chrome does not allow  Worker in the local server)

Any help is highly appreciated as I am stuck in this in 4 days already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you pleas clarify what you main task is?
If I understood it right you want to display a PDF file that already exists in a part of your application? You don't want to create a new PDF with JavaScript.

If you want to just show a PDF have you tried to use `iframe`?
Something like this:

```
<iframe
   title="file"
   style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
   src={downloadURL}
/>
```

You ca use here also relative paths to the file from the location where your Component is or use full URLs to the file.

Comment: It works for me as a magic! Thank you very much, Tarik. It was too bad that I only searched for some react pdf packages.

Comment: I can use the URL for the file in local server.  

I cannot use relative path to the file from the location where my Component is. So it fails to show the static pdf on Heroku server.  

As I use Django in the backend, I am thinking about setting Django serving static file to be able to have the URL from Heroku server to provide for the iframe.   

Is there any better solution?  

@Tarik, do you need to use some loader for the pdf file in webpack to be able to use the relative path?

Comment: You would need to use a loader. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643649/serving-static-pdf-with-react-webpack-file-loader The PDF needs to be callable from your code if you use a relative path or the web if you call it over a URL so both of your suggestions should work. You just need to chose the one that fits the most your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the link, @Tarik. I have already tried that link and some other ones but I failed. So again, I am stuck in setting some file loader for PDF file.  
I am trying to set Django PDF serving now.

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you indeed! react-pdf package does not provide adequate manual on how to send data from the backend.