# Unable to download pdf in react application on local

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> I am creating a portfolio using reactjs , Unable to download the
>   resume pdf file on clicking . I get message as no file.
>
> Here is my Resume component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Resume.css';
import resume from '../doc/ResumeAbhishek.pdf';

class Resume extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <center>RESUME DOWNLOAD</center>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <center>
                            <a type="button" className="btn btn-secondary btn-lg"
                            href={resume}
                            download="ResumeAbhishek.pdf">
                                <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true" />
                                &nbsp; Resume</a>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Resume;
```

Comment: Failed - no file when i click that button

Comment: can you show the output of `console.log(resume)`

Comment: maybe your pdf file is not going in the build folder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643649/serving-static-pdf-with-react-webpack-file-loader

Comment: /static/media/ResumeAbhishek.dc82283f.pdf   for   console.log(resume);

Comment: this path has your pdf file or not?

Comment: ya i am getting intellisense for that path right

Comment: problem with pdf itself as it dint open normally also

Answer (score 1):

Why are you importing from a pdf? Your href should be a path to the file, something like this should work:

```
 <a type="button" 
    className="btn btn-secondary btn-lg"
    href='/path/to/ResumeAbhishek.pdf'
    download>
 </a>
```

Comment: still i get no file

Comment: Are you able to access your static files anyhow? Are they being served normally? Doesn't seem like a problem with the download itself.

Comment: problem with pdf itself as it dint open normally also