# View pdf file in react app throwing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to open pdf file in react app on menu click but getting this error

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, 
currently no loaders are configured to process this file
```

I have static pdf file in my project directory, I would like just open it in a new tab in menu click event.

The pdf file itself is not really large about 7mb

What is the best way to do it ?

```js
import testPDF from "../assets/pdf/test.pdf";

  const handleOpenPDF = () => {
    window.open(testPDF);
  }

  <Menu.Item onClick={handleOpenPDF}>
    <Text>
      View PDF
    </Text>
  </Menu.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the https://react-pdf.org/ library. Should be able to install it, import it, then include it in your code like so:

```
import { Document } from 'react-pdf';

const handleOpenPDF = () => {
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Document
      file={testPDF}
      onLoadSuccess={() => console.log('PDF successfully loaded!')}
    >
      <p>Loading PDF...</p>
    </Document>,
    container
  );
  window.open().document.write(container.innerHTML);
};
```

Hope this helps! React-pdf is a great, user-friendly library.

Comment: but I'm still getting error during compiling ```Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)```

Comment: Perhaps this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643649/serving-static-pdf-with-react-webpack-file-loader?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the fact you are importing the PDF file like it was a JS module.
You should serve your pdf as a static file on your server instead and use a the static file URL to display/download it.